# How to pass color as parameter in c#?

Tags: c#, colors, console-application

I need to change font color many times in console app.
Instead of typing (or copying) each time :
`Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.MyColor;` in my code,
I want to type only
`c(Red)` or `c(Yellow)`.
I thaough about something like this:

```
static void c(<???> myColor){
   Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.MyColor;
}
```

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: `static void c(ConsoleColor myColor){ Console.ForegroundColor = myColor; }`

Comment: Still i have to call the method like this: `c(ConsoleColor.Red);`. Is there a way to shorten it to: c(Red) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing `c(Red)` pass `c(ConsoleColor.Red)` and use parameter of type `ConsoleColor` enum in defination of method `c()`

```
public static void c(ConsoleColor myColor){
   Console.ForegroundColor = myColor;
}
```

Call function using

```
c(ConsoleColor.Red);
```

[MSDN ConsoleColor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.consolecolor?view=netcore-3.1)

---

> I want to type only c(Red) or c(Yellow)

If you want to pass string called `Red` or `Yellow` and assign `ForegroundColor` to your console, then you can try below

```
public static void SetForegroundColor(string colorName)
{
   //Set black as foreground color if TryParse fails to parse color string. 
   if(Enum.TryParse(ConsoleColor, colorName, out ConsoleColor color)
       Console.ForegroundColor = color;
   else
       Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;

}
```

Now you can pass color name as a string to this function, Like

```
SetForegroundColor("Red");
SetForegroundColor("Yello");
```

[MSDN: Enum.TryPrase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: it's `ConsoleColor` not `ColorConsole`.

Comment: @user13796818, did you get chance to look into my answer? Was it helpful?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Prasad Telkikar. I used your sec suggestion. I made it more shorter by defining few colors in string variables `string w = "White", r = "Red", y = "Yellow", b = "Blue", g = "Green", cy = "Cyan", m = "Magenta", gr= "Gray";` . Now I can do exactly what i wanted to (even shorter!): `c(r);`   (about the first parameter in the TryPare `ConsoleColor`, what is this for ? actually the VS didn't get it...so i delete it and it works).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method you can use to set the foreground color of your Console. I named the function as `SetConsoleForeground`  but you can set it as you like such as `c`

```
/// <summary>
/// Sets Console Foreground color to the given color
/// </summary>
/// <param name="consoleColor">Foreground color to set</param>
private static void SetConsoleForeground Color(ConsoleColor consoleColor) {
    Console.ForegroundColor = consoleColor;
}
```

Comment: I am too beginner to understand it... but what exactly is the two names `SetConsoleForeground` and `Color` ? And also why is it `private` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public  class ConsoleExtension
{
    static Dictionary<char, ConsoleColor> colors = new Dictionary<char, ConsoleColor>
        {
            {'w', ConsoleColor.White },
            {'g', ConsoleColor.Green },
            {'r', ConsoleColor.Red },
            {'b', ConsoleColor.Blue },
            {'y', ConsoleColor.Yellow },
            {'m', ConsoleColor.Magenta }
        };
    public static void CC(char color = 'w')
    {
        try
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = colors[color];
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Color isn't correct");
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can call `CC('g')` to change ForeGroundColor to green for example

Or you can use snippet like that:

```
CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
<Header>
    <Title>Change textColor and WriteLine</Title>
    <Author>IZ</Author>
    <Shortcut>cwc</Shortcut>
    <Description>Set your text color</Description>
    <SnippetTypes>
        <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
    </SnippetTypes>
</Header>
<Snippet>
    <Declarations>
        <Literal>
            <ID>TextColor</ID>
            <Default>Green</Default>
        </Literal>
        <Literal>
            <ID>Text</ID>
            <Default>Text</Default>
        </Literal>
    </Declarations>
    <Code Language="CSharp">
        <![CDATA[Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.$TextColor$;
        Console.WriteLine("$Text$");]]>
    </Code>
</Snippet>
```

It's even much better because now you can use it everywhere and it's shorter - type 'cwc' and TAB only

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
Console.WriteLine("Text");
```